# How to mock.patch MySQLdb.cursors?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

```
class CanonDatabase:
    def __init__(self, clean_up_db=False):
        self.db = "tmg_canon_april_tokens"
        self.conn = create_connection(self.db)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

I am trying to mock.patch MySQLdb in order to pass the constructor.

```
@mock.patch.object(MySQLdb, '__init__')
class TestDatabase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TestDatabase, self).setUp()
        patch = mock.patch('atone_canon.Database.create_connection')
        mock_baz = patch.start()
        mock_baz.cursor.return_value = mock.MagicMock()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(TestDatabase, self).tearDown()
        mock.patch.stopall()

    def test_clean_table(self, mysql_mock):
        db = CanonDatabase()
        self.assertEqual(True, False)
```

However this fails with the following error message:

> ```
> File "atone_canon/Database.py", line 20, in __init__ self.cur = self.conn.cursor(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cursors'

**I found a way:**

If I insert this import in my unit test, without (!) even using it:

```
from MySQLdb.cursors import DictCursor
```

Then I no longer get the error, and I won't even have to mock.patch the MySQLdb wrapper:

```
# @mock.patch.object(MySQLdb, '__init__')
class TestDatabase(unittest.TestCase):
   ...
```

Not too happy with the solution. Generally I have difficulties with mocking classes that live outside my project (e.g. live in the virtualenv). I leave this open, so hopefully someone can show me how to mock these kind of classes.

Comment: did you try to mock MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor similar way you do in setUp for your custom class? as it looks like you mock MySQLdb.__init__ and then expect to find MySQLdb.cursors which correctly does not exist

Comment: Not sure how to do that. `patch_dict_cursor = mock.patch.object(DictCursor, '__init__')`  Would that work?

Comment: think you will need something more akin to this: patch_dict_cursor = mock.patch(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor, spec=True)

Comment: That didn't work either. I get this: `AttributeError: type object 'DictCursor' has no attribute 'rsplit'`. However this here has worked: `mock.patch('MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor')`

Comment: If you are still interested on this question a post an answer that explain what is your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will test this soon and let you know the outcome, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: **make sure** you have in `Database.py`

```
import MySQLdb.cursors
```

Otherwise your mentioned error will be raised even if you don't patch anything. If you want double check it add `cur=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor` at the top of `__init__` and remove all patches: you will find the same error raised in the new line. That error will disappear if you load `MySQLdb.cursors` somewhere in your context before try to point `MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor`. If you are wondered that you haven't see that error before is because in your production code you import `MySQLdb.cursors` before use `CanonDatabase()`

Now make a test where your constructor will pass and `create_connection` *evil* function don't try to connect anything can be obtained simply by patching just `create_connection` and anything else:

```
class TestSimpler(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('atone_canon.Database.create_connection')
    def test_base(self, mock_create_connection):
        db = CanonDatabase()
        self.assertIsNotNone(db)
```

Of course you can decorate test class if you want patch `create_connection` for every test methods.